# How do set up something similar to GAMS' circular indexing for Pyomo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo, gams-math

I'm working on a pyomo constraint that has a rule in the first loop to do some calculation based on the last loop. So for T = 24, each loop is:

```
def const1(model,t):
    return model.x[t] == model.x[t - 1] + ef_H * model.d[t] - model.g[t]
model.x_const = Constraint(T, rule=const1)
```

In the first loop however, I want it to use the value from the last loop and do the calculation, like so:

```
def const1(model,t):
    if t == 0:
          return model.x[t] == model.x[24] + ef_H * model.d[t] - model.g[t]
    return model.x[t] == model.x[t - 1] + ef_H * model.d[t] - model.g[t]
model.x_const = Constraint(T, rule=const1)
```

I know in GAMS, there's the -- command, that you can set something like:

```
model.x[t] == model.x[t -- 1] + ef_H * model.d[t] - model.g[t]
```

and it will use the last value (t = 24) to calculate your initial model.x[t]. Is there a simple way in pyomo that can achieve this?

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Comment: why don't you just do it as you are now by handling the special case with the `if` statement?  Also, your `Constraint()` call is going to barf because you are passing in `S` and `T` but only catching 1 parameter...

Comment: @AirSquid: thanks for catching the extra S. I was just wondering if pyomo can do something like GAMS without using the extra if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `T` is a list of elements for a set known as `'T'` in the model. You will need to define this set as `ordered` to make this work. Then you can use the pyomo [`Set.prevw`](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pyomo/core/base/set.html?highlight=prevw) method, which gives you the previous member of a set, wrapping if needed. I would also recommend defining that set as part of the model, rather than a free-floating object.

So you can write fairly simple code like this:

```
model.T = Set(initialize=T, ordered=True)

def const1(model, t):
    return model.x[t] == model.x[model.T.prevw(t)] + ef_H * model.d[t] - model.g[t]
model.x_const = Constraint(model.T, rule=const1)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes.  This is good.  I didn't know of this method!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are "doing math" on the indices when you do `t-1` that implies that the elements of the set `T` are consecutive integers.  If the set `T` contained letters or colors or whatever, it's not going to work.  I'm not sure what GAMS would do in that case.  In general, sets do not have any order.  You *could* use an ordered set in `pyomo` which will allow you to access the set elements by index, but that probably doesn't help too much here.  I think the way you have it now is fine, but you could do...

```
In [23]: m = ConcreteModel()                                                              

In [24]: a = ['A', 'B', 'C']   # just to show it w/ string values                         

In [25]: m.T = Set(ordered=True, initialize=a)                                            

In [26]: m.T[1]   #pyomo ordered sets are 1-indexed !!!!!                                 
Out[26]: 'A'

In [27]: m.T[-1]  #python standard for getting the last value in an interable             
Out[27]: 'C'

In [28]: # introduce m.x ...                                                              

In [29]: m.x = Var(m.T)                                                                   

In [30]: m.x[m.T[-1]]  # ref to the last value...                                         
Out[30]: <pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData at 0x7fc233189040>
```