# pyomo: how to index Variable in only part of a Set?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to keep track of SOCs in a `pyomo` optimization model. I have number of BEVs and I want to keept track of eachs SOC. The xpression I pass to `pe.Objective` looks like the following:

```
sum(sum(model.SOC[t+1, b] - model.SOC[t, b] for b in model.buses) for t in model.times)
```

`model.buses` and `model.times` are two Sets I have declared as `pe.Set`. The times go from (0, ...., 95). So in the last iteration for the `model.times` it tries to access `model.SOC[96, b]` what leads to a `KeyError`.

Is there a way to tell pyomo to leafe out the last element of the set to prevent this Error?

Somethin like:

```
sum(sum(model.SOC[t+1, b] - model.SOC[t, b] for b in model.buses) for t in model.times[0:-2])
```

which sadly also raises an Error:

```
IndexError: times indices must be integers, not slice
```

here is a minmal example that should reproduce the Error:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')
model = pe.ConcreteModel('Test')
model.times = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(96)))
model.buses = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(5)))
model.SOC = pe.Var(model.times*model.buses, domain=pe.PositiveReals)

def example_rule(model):
    return sum(sum(model.SOC[t+1, b] - model.SOC[t, b] for b in model.buses) for t in model.times)

model.obj = pe.Objective(rule=example_rule, sense=pe.maximize)

model.pprint()
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple ways to do this.  First, if the set that you want to index into is ordered (which is default), you can use the `first`, `last`, and `prev` methods on the set in various ways.  (see my edits to your code below)

Second, you can always construct your own subset and either place it in the model or not.  Second model below shows construction of an arbitrarily complicated subset and puts it in the model.  This set could be used as basis for an objective or constraint.

This solution is similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763822/how-do-set-up-something-similar-to-gams-circular-indexing-for-pyomo/68764201#68764201)

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')
model = pe.ConcreteModel('Test')
model.times = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(5)), ordered=True)  # ordered is default, this is for clarity...
model.buses = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(2)))
model.SOC = pe.Var(model.times*model.buses, domain=pe.PositiveReals)

def example_rule(model):
    return sum(sum(model.SOC[t+1, b] - model.SOC[t, b] for b in model.buses) for t in model.times if t != model.times.last())

model.obj = pe.Objective(rule=example_rule, sense=pe.maximize)

model.pprint()


# making your own subset...
times = 10
model2 = pe.ConcreteModel("other")
model2.times = pe.Set(initialize=range(times))
# make a subset of the even values that are no more than 4 values close to the end....
model2.times_subset = pe.Set(initialize=[t for t in model2.times if t%2==0 and t <= times-4])

model2.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
3 Set Declarations
    SOC_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain      : Size : Members
        None :     2 : times*buses :   10 : {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 1)}
    buses : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}
    times : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    5 : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

1 Var Declarations
    SOC : Size=10, Index=SOC_index
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (0, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (0, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (1, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (1, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (2, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (2, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (3, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (3, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (4, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        (4, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : maximize : SOC[1,0] - SOC[0,0] + SOC[1,1] - SOC[0,1] + SOC[2,0] - SOC[1,0] + SOC[2,1] - SOC[1,1] + SOC[3,0] - SOC[2,0] + SOC[3,1] - SOC[2,1] + SOC[4,0] - SOC[3,0] + SOC[4,1] - SOC[3,1]

5 Declarations: times buses SOC_index SOC obj
2 Set Declarations
    times : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :   10 : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    times_subset : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {0, 2, 4, 6}

2 Declarations: times times_subset
[Finished in 553ms]
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! :) This `prevw` solves my problem. Is there a place on the internet where one can learn this? In the pyomo documentation `prevw` isn't even mentioned (or at least I haven't seen it)

Comment: Yeah, IMHO, the Pyomo documentation covers the basics, but is lacking in good module documentation.  This is "okay" but not great...  I wouldn't have known `prevw` without that other post.  Sometimes I tinker in `ipython` which shows completions and doc stubs.  https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/expr_dev/_modules/index.html